# Loop through and create and new dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, loops, numpy, dataframe

I have a Shared folder where .CSV files are be stored...
 i will take all the .CSV file to do my manipulation

```
import glob
x = glob.glob(r'C:\Users\Desktop\files\*.csv')
# x  has path of all the file, say i have 3 file in folder
i=0
while i < len(x):

df=pd.read_csv(x[i],header=1)
#x[i] is full file path,so now we assumed we have 3 files 
..
# Some data manipulation
..
print(avg)
# with 3 file, 3 different AVG value calculated
print(sum)
# with 3 file, 3 different SUM value calculated
i += 1
```

Now i want a new Data Frame as below..

also file name should not be entire path..

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Below, it works:

```
import glob
x = glob.glob(r'C:\Users\Desktop\files\*.csv')
i=0
avglist = []
sumlist = []
while i < len(x):
    df=pd.read_csv(x[i],header=1)
    #x[i] is full file path
    ..
    # Some data manipulation
    ..
    #print(avg)
    avglist.append(avg)
    #print(sum)
    sumlist.append(sum)
    i += 1
df = pd.DataFrame({"File Name": x, "Average": avglist, "Sum": sumlist})
```

Comment: File Name | Average | Sum
0 C:\Users\Desktop\aptiv.csv | apt: (Worldwide) 358.833333 dtype: float64| aptiv: (Worldwide) 789 dtype: int64

​

Comment: I am not able to understand the issue, therefore I am unable to help you. Please could you be more clear..?

Comment: SUM :
Count: (Worldwide) 584 dtype: int64 :
Count: (Worldwide) 584 dtype: int64

Comment: when i pass avglist column to dataframe... it will  have datatype description ,column description also...